# An DPDK error about "Cannot create lock on 'var/run/dpdk/rte/config'. "

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, dpdk

I tried to run two applications on one server, when I run the second application, the following error will be reported:

> Cannot create lock on 'var/run/dpdk/rte/config'.

How should I solve this problem so that I can run multiple DPDK programs at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's done with the [EAL parameter](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_eal_parameters.html) `--file-prefix`.

You'd run one program with `--file-prefix <prefix 1>` and the second one with `--file-prefix <prefix 2>` (any unique names will do).  Since it's an EAL parameter, make sure that it gets passed to the program *before* the `--` parameter separator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that the <prefix 1> and <prefix 2> here can be any unique names, not necessarily a specific file path?

Comment: Correct.  They are just file name prefixes, and not path prefixes.  Here is a more informative link about [multi-process support in DPDK](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/multi_proc_support.html).  See in particular section 44.2.3.  It's probably also appropriate to mention that if you *do* want inter-process collaboration, you can enable it by using the same file-prefix.